# When a parcelable object is passed through an intent, does it update with references to the original object?

Tags: android, android-intent

Lets say I have a Product object that has a pricetag property. I also have a List of Stores, each with its own list of Products.

Specifically, Product p has price $9.99, and a Store s which is in the Store list had p in its product list.

I have this store List in an android activity, and I pass Product p to another activity through an intent, and then change that object's price in the new Activity. Once I finish this new Activity and return to the old one, are the changes made to that object reflected in Store s's product list?

Comment: The answer is No. When you are passing a parcelable object to new activity then the reference of the object is different than old one. If you want to get new parice then use `startActivityResult()` and get upadted product object in `onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No the references are not maintained. A parcel is:

> Container for a message (data and object references) that can
>    be sent through an IBinder.  A Parcel can contain both flattened data
>    that will be unflattened on the other side of the IPC (using the various
>    methods here for writing specific types, or the general
>    Parcelable interface), and references to live IBinder
>    objects that will result in the other side receiving a proxy IBinder
>    connected with the original IBinder in the Parcel.

If you look at any parcelable, there is a `CREATOR`. That creates a new object out of the `Parcel`. 
For example:

```
 public static final Creator<Employee> CREATOR = new Creator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public Employee createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Employee(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Employee[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Employee[size];
    }
};
```

So you if want any data *back* from another activity, use `startActivityForResult` as Lawrance mentioned.